# Error in if (object$offset) { : argument is of length zero in relaxnet R package

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I want to perform a cross validation to select tuning parameter for **relaxed lasso** model using `relaxnet` package. Below I have attached a sample code that is closely related to the one from `relaxnet` vignette but with a two level factor as a response variable:

```
nobs <- 100
nvars <- 200
set.seed(23)

x <- matrix(rnorm(nobs * nvars), nobs, nvars)
colnames(x) <- paste("x", 1:ncol(x), sep = "")

y<-rbinom(nobs,1,.75)
y<-as.factor(y)

cv.result <- cv.relaxnet(x, y,family="binomial")
```

I get the following error after the execution of `cv.relaxnet` function:

> Error in if (object$offset) { : argument is of length zero

I will be very grateful for any comments and ideas.